# How to correctly use jquery noConflict for pop up elements in cakephp

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp

I have a very weird scenario. I have an old code base that I have taken over, each page loads a single jquery version as specified in the layout.

However we have had to make some of the pop ups on these page responsive using bootstrap. My problem is, is that I can't change the jquery version to cater for bootstrap without breaking the JS that runs in the page.

Therefore I am trying to apply the noconflict method provided by Jquery to an element that is a pop up

```
<?php $this->Js->JqueryEngine->jQueryObject = '$j';
echo $this->Html->scriptBlock(
'var $j = jQuery.noConflict();',
array('inline' => false)
); ?>
<script type="text/javascript"    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js">  </script>

<div class="modal fade" id="logModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="logModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title login_register_boot" id="logModalLabel">Already registered? Login now</h4>
        </div>

        <?php echo $this->Form->create('CustomUser', array('url' => array('controller' => 'custom_users', 'action' => 'ajax_login',
        'inputDefaults' => array(
            'label' => array('class' => 'false')
        )
        ))); ?>
        <fieldset class="modal-body">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 login_margin_top">
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('username', array('type' => 'text', 'id' => 'inputUsername3', 'placeholder' => 'Username')); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 login_margin_top_bot">
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('password', array('type' => 'password', 'id' => 'inputPassword4', 'placeholder' => 'Password')); ?>
            </div>

            <?php echo $this->Js->submit('Login', 
            array(
        'url' => array(
        'controller' => 'custom_users',
        'action' => 'ajax_login'
        ),
        'update' => '#login-content',
        'before' => '$("#loading").fadeIn("slow");',
        'complete' => '$("#loading").fadeOut("slow");',
        'class' => 'btn btn_submit fl login_margin col-xs-12 col-sm-4'
    )
            );?>

            <a class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4" id="forgot-password" href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
            <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
        </fieldset>
    <div class="modal-footer">      
            <a data-toggle="modal" style="outline: none;" data-target="#regModal" href="#regModal">Not registered? Register now</a>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So basically I want all the bootstrap related stuff in here to use the jquery versions above, and the rest of the page to use the older jquery versions loaded in the layout. I'm battling to get this to work. Have I misunderstood how to use noConflict, and if so how do I use noConflict in this scenario?

Comment: You are calling `noConflict` before you even load the jQuery source. I doubt that bootstrap won't work with 1.9.1 and that you need any of this

Comment: The JS they use on the page is very very old, and bootstrap won't work with it. I loaded 1.9.1 specifically for it. Gonna try your suggestion now, thanks.

Comment: Loading the new library before I called no conflict didn't work either.

Comment: so what errors get thrown? I still don't think you need both versions anyway. There is nothing new in 1.11 that shouldn't also work in 1.9

Comment: Certain functions like .live have been replaced for example. But when using the old jquery version, the pop ups, don't pop up, they load with the page and onto the page, which looks quite unsightly.

Comment: I've got the JS working just fine now. However the bootstrap css is conflicting with the original pages' css, is there a similar no conflict for css?

Comment: No, css doesn't work that way. You could custom build bootstrap per your needs though. Personally if all you need are some popups there are lots of other alternatives that don't require loading a full css framework